# google map works in local but when i move to live it show empty page

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

this works in local fine when i change it to like it's showing empty ..
here we have any thing else in this code?? i mean in php or map canvas

```
<style type="text/css">
                body { font: normal 10pt Helvetica, Arial; }
                #map { width: 350px; height: 300px; border: 0px; padding: 0px; }
            </style>
            <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                //Sample code written by August Li
                var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
                           new google.maps.Size(32, 32), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                           new google.maps.Point(16, 32));
                var center = null;
                var map = null;
                var currentPopup;
                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
                    var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                    bounds.extend(pt);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: pt,
                        icon: icon,
                        map: map
                    });
                    var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: info,
                        maxWidth: 300
                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                        if (currentPopup != null) {
                            currentPopup.close();
                            currentPopup = null;
                        }
                        popup.open(map, marker);
                        currentPopup = popup;
                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
                        map.panTo(center);
                        currentPopup = null;
                    });
                }           
                function initMap() {
                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
                        zoom: 14,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                        mapTypeControl: true,
                        mapTypeControlOptions: {
                            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
                        },
                        navigationControl: true,
                        navigationControlOptions: {
                            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.ZOOM_PAN
                        }
                    });
    <?php
    // here $product_info['products_state']=state code
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM states where abv = '" .$product_info['products_state']. "'")or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
      $name = $row['name'];
      $lat = $row['latitude'];
      $lon = $row['longitude'];
      $desc = $row['abv'];



      echo("addMarker($lat, $lon, '<b>$name</b><br />$desc');\n");

    }

    ?>
     center = bounds.getCenter();
         map.fitBounds(bounds);

         }
         </script>
         </head>
         <body onLoad="initMap()" style="margin:0px; border:0px; padding:0px;">
         <div id="map"></div>
         </body>
```

for this i have add any api code here ? where can i put my api?

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: the particular field(map frame) shows white space

Comment: No. If you view source in the browser do you see obvious problems or get javascript errors?

Comment: here no java script problem now i noticed in my page 2 body tags are there one for hole page another one for map ,please suggest how to convert map body tag to div here i changed but it's getting error

Answer (score 0):

Add a colored border (via developer tool) to the map div and check if it's not overshadowed by any other HTML element. Use the browser error console to check if there's any javascript error while page renders.